# display decimal with comma instead of decimal with dot

Tags: c#, parsing, decimal

How can I display decimals with commas instead of decimal with dot in C#.

I got this problem while I have to enter decimal with comma format and I make my calculation but in the browsers I see numbers with dot !

Answer (score 4):

You can create a `CultureInfo` and specify that decimal separator will be `,`:

```
var info = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.Clone() as CultureInfo;
info.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ",";

double n = 123.456;
Console.WriteLine(n.ToString(info));
```

Output:

```
"123,456"
```

Answer (score 2):

It depends on you culture. If you specify the culture that uses comma all decimals wil be displayed with ",". If you need dot, choose the culture that uses "."